# How to add additional length to wav file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I can merge wav into one file.

I need to know 
how to add additional 5 seconds silence length end of the wav file using ffmpeg without merging 5 seconds silent wav file. I just try some codes:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.wav -i silent1.wav -i input2.wav -i silent2.wav ....
```

Comment: What's with the C# tag?

Comment: are there any solution for that doing with c#

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Add a silence input in this way `-f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc` and use it wherever you want.